# I am getting AssertionError while freezing my keras model graph

Tags: tensorflow, keras

`AssertionError: dense_5/Softmax is not in graph`

Summary of my model looks like this:
[image]

code to freeze graph

`frozen_graph = freeze_graph(tf.compat.v1.Session(), output_names = [model.output.op.name])`

the freeze graph function is from the file
https://github.com/shubhammor0403/EMNIST/blob/master/fg.py

I have included the file as fg.py in my code

Comment: How you are freezing your model? post your code along with full error trace.

Comment: please check, I have updated the question.